# No cache-control on Atom feed

Tags: feature-request, support, caching, atom

I made my own Atom parser on my server to parse some Atom feed from stackoverflow. But this ressource don't have cache-control. For instance if you fetch headers of https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby-on-rails you can see this header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Mon, 26 Apr 2010 12:40:09 GMT
Content-Length: 849
```

So I can't know if this atom change or not. Therefor I need fetch the entire response of this request. If there were a simple HTTP cache with 304 or etag or last-modified, I could avoid fetching this request each time.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution.

date last question asked link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=ruby-on-rails&sort=newest&pagesize=1

date last question modified link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=ruby-on-rails&sort=active&pagesize=1

This response will be much shorter and you can isolate the date in "title" property of the first span tag inside  the div class="user-action-time" tag.

I hope this helps.

```
<div class="user-action-time">asked <span title="2010-05-10 05:55:41Z"


        <div class="excerpt"> 
            I recently played with MongoDB in Rails using Mongoid. I like the ability to define attributes for models within the model file (as opposed to in migrations):

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
 &hellip; 
            <div class="started"> 
                <div class="user-info"><div class="user-action-time">asked <span title="2010-05-10 05:55:41Z" class="relativetime">13 mins ago</span></div><div class="user-gravatar32"><a href="/users/259900/kevin-sylvestre"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c78e40f8fc27a048f10ece6956a2fdf2?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" height="32" width="32" alt=""></a></div><div class="user-details"><a href="/users/259900/kevin-sylvestre" >Kevin Sylvestre</a><br><span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score">743</span><span title="2 silver badges"><span class="badge2">&#9679;</span><span class="badgecount">2</span></span><span title="8 bronze badges"><span class="badge3">&#9679;</span><span class="badgecount">8</span></span></div></div> 
            </div>  

            <div class="tags t-ruby-on-rails"> 
                <a href="/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'ruby-on-rails'" rel="tag">ruby-on-rails</a> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes it's works, but HTTP is so powerfull. Why it can be used like questions